# Is it possible for a scalar (or vector) field to be non-smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Can a 2-dimensional scalar field have a discontinuous contour curve?
How about contour curves that intersect -- possible?

On a related note: can a vector field have a domain that is not defined over a continuous region??

Comment: The title doesn't match the actual question.

Comment: Even smooth scalar fields can have contour curves that intersect or consist of several disconnected pieces. Consider for example $xy=0$ or $xy=1$.

Comment: The concept of scalar field I'm being given is a physical one: "An n-dimensional scalar field is a distribution of scalar values in n-dimensional space, and is represented mathematically by a scalar function of n variables." But you guys seem to treat "scalar field" as being synonymous with "scalar function".

Comment: @Ryan: Is "made up of points that don't join up" an euphemism for "discontinuous"?

Comment: @rod Oops, yes; I have duely edited my question for concision.

Comment: @Ryan: Doesn't the phrase "is represented mathematically by a scalar function of n variables" say exactly that you can treat "scalar field" as being synonymous with "scalar function"?

Comment: @HansLundmark Well, there was also the possibility that the set of scalar fields is not a mapping *onto* the set of scalar functions.... (i.e. there could exist functions that don't represent any scalar field)

Comment: Then they should have specified which scalar functions they were talking about. ;-) Anyway, physicists may very well be interested in discontinuous scalar fields, for example an idealized shock wave in a fluid, where there's a jump in the pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, the scalar field $f (x,y) := x y$ has discontinuous contour curves. Note that $f (x,y) = 1$ yields two hyperbolas:

[image: Two hyperbolas]

Animated plot courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbola_construction_-_parallelogram_method.gif).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many *ugly* functions.. it also depends what do you mean by a 2 dimensional *scalar field* (because one usually consider them at least continuous by definition).

So, for example, take the following function:
$$(x,y) \mapsto \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \text{if }x,y\in\mathbb Q \\
1 & \text{else}
\end{matrix} \right. $$

Comment: "it also depends what do you mean by a 2 dimensional scalar field (because one usually consider them at least continuous by definition)." This is precisely what I'm trying to figure out: are scalar fields **continuous** functions by definition?? My intuition tells me yes (and also, the concept of contour curves, etc., all seem to point towards this), yet I can't find any definition that mandates that scalar fields be **continuous** functions.